# retrieve all images path from string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

How do I get all images path from a string?
Note I just want the path containing the word "media".

For example given this string (part of the DOM)

```
<div class="my-class">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.jpeg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/2017/10/img68.png" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.jpg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <h2 class="uk-margin-top-remove">About us</h2>                
</div>
```

I want an array containing a similar result:

```
array(
  [0] => "http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.png"
  [1] => "http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.png"
);
```

I don't want the second img because src attribute doesn't contain the word "media".

Comment: please state your current attempt

Comment: You have been a member long enough to know you should include code.

Comment: Dig into DOMDocument object, and try something out. Learning is best by attempting! You'll also stumble across all kinds of fun new things while you try. ... and you have way too many questions without accepted answers.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Use a parser: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Doing a simple search like. `php get src from img` gives you lots of answers. Then you can easily tailor it to your issue. FYI `regex` is not ideal here. `DOMDocument()` is right

Comment: I would use a parser but I can't in this particular case.

Comment: @ctwheels: I could say the same with the pony link but I wouldn't dare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all()` to get URLs but it is even better to use a DOM reader.

```
$str = '<div class="my-class">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.jpeg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/2017/10/img68.png" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.jpg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <h2 class="uk-margin-top-remove">About us</h2>                
</div>' ;

$matches = [] ;
preg_match_all('~(http\://my-website\.com/cache/media/(.*?))"~i', $str, $matches) ;
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Will returns :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(52) "http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  string(51) "http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some boilerplate code to get you started:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div class="my-class">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.jpeg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/2017/10/img68.png" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <img src="http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.jpg" class="" alt="test" width="120" height="100">
   <h2 class="uk-margin-top-remove">About us</h2>                
</div>
DATA;

# set up the dom
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);# | LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NOENT );

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//img[contains(@src, '/media/')]/@src") as $image) {
    echo $image->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Which yields

```
http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img67.jpeg
http://my-website.com/cache/media/2017/10/img69.jpg
```

---

This loads the `DOM` and uses an `xpath` query for every image where we'll loop over afterwards.

---

If for some reasons (why?) you are unable to use a `DOM` parser, your could use the secondbest option:

```
<img
(?s:(?!>).)+?
src=(['"])
(?P<src>(?:(?!\1).)+?/media/.*?\1)
```

And use the `src` group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qgTvuB/1/).

Comment: I was waiting for the Jan parser answer. User only wants URLs containing `media` though

Comment: @ctwheels: Updated thanks. I might get a bit calmer once I got the golden `regex` badge (only two to go!)

Comment: ++ posted very similar then realized your answer :)

Comment: I deleted it as that looks like a dup answer